Explicitly finding a finite abelian group from a presentation, $\langle a, b~|~a^n = b^n=1, ab=ba, ab^{-1}ab^{-1}=1\rangle$
I have the following group presentation:
$
G= \langle a, b~|~a^n = b^n=1, ab=ba, ab^{-1}ab^{-1}=1\rangle
$
It is clear that $G$ is a finite abelian group. I am interested in knowing what exactly $G$ is. I have done the following calculations:
Clearly, $G$ is isomorphic to the following presentation:
$ \langle a, x~|~ a^n=x^n=1, ax=xa, x^2=1 \rangle$
Case 1: $n$ is odd
Then, the subgroup generated by $x^2$ is $\langle x \rangle $. Thus
$G \cong \langle a~|~ a^n \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_n$
Case 2: $n$ is even
Then $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_n \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2.$
Can someone confirm whether I am doing it correctly?
Is there any other more direct way to find $G$ explicitly?

You can use the Smith Normal Form to find the normal form of the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ generated by $(n,0)$, $(0,n)$, and $(2,-2)$.

You're almost there:
$$\begin{align}
G&\cong \langle a, b\mid a^n = b^n=1, ab=ba, ab^{-1}ab^{-1}=1\rangle\\
&\cong \langle a, x\mid a^n=x^n=1, ax=xa, x^2=1 \rangle\\
&\cong \langle a,x\mid a^n=1, x^{\gcd(n,2)}=1, ax=xa\rangle\\
&\cong \Bbb Z_n\times \Bbb Z_{\gcd(n,2)}.
\end{align}$$

Can you explain a bit about the third step? I am not able to understand the reason behind it. If in place of 2 we have some other number say m, would it be gcd(n,m) then?

@eyp: Because $$(g^a=e\land g^b=e)\iff g^{\gcd(a,b)}=e.$$
